# npm installation error CLI

Tags: angularjs, npm-install

I tried to install npm and run angular project but there is a warning

[image]

I ran this command `npm install -g @angular/cli` after installing `git` and `node`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing package.json from your project. Since you have installed angular/cli globally, you should just create new project as `ng new nameofproject`

See here for more info https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

You need to have package.json file using which npm downloads dependencies for the project. Create a new project with the following command ng new projectName.

Answer (score 0):

You are here:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\angular>npm install
```

instead use:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\angular>ng new myangular-app
```

When you do this it will create and download all the required files and dependencies. After this you are good to go then.

[image]

Hope this helps!

PS: Please have patience, as this can take some time to set up your new project. (It will download all the required files and dependencies to **`node_modules`** folder).